# Calculate center frequency for a given signal in frequency domain

Tags: python-3.x, center, frequency

I have a signal (points in frequency domain (nanometers, then converted to tera hertz; along with magnitude level in mW). My signal looks like the attached pic. I would like to know a way to calculate the center frequency.
One theory suggests finding the -3dB cutoff frequencies on both ends. However, I could not find how to do that. So, please tell me how to calculate the -3dB cutoff frequencies so that I can apply te following formula- (f1+f2)/2
or suggest me a better way of finding the center frequency.

[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You need to understand that dB is an abbreviation for [Decibel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decibel).  There's a convenient chart at the link that tells you exactly what -3dB means.

Answer (score 0):

You could perform this measurement as an OBW measurement. - 3dB is when you half the total signal power by 50%. (in Watts)
The way to do it manually is to get the whole signal spectrum in an excel table, for example 1000 points, measure the total power, Ptot, and start adding the power by the lowest frequency until you reach 25% of Ptot. The frequency at that point will be Flow. Do the same, but starting from the top frequency until you reach 25% of Ptot. it will be Fhigh. The center will be (Flow + Fhigh)/2.

Sorry if it's not very clear but if you look for OBW measurements You should find better explanations on the net. Most of modern spectrum analyzers have this function built in.